# absolute position causing a jump to the top of the containing div onclick of a label/checkbox

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms, layout

Im having issues with the user being taken to the top of a scrollable div (absolute position) when clicking a label/checkbox.

[Code](https://codepen.io/demooooo/pen/eYJWXEZ)

Ive tried various things on an onclick on each of the 4 labels (see below) but unfortunately nothing is working.

```
div.scrollIntoView();
div.scrollTop = div.scrollHeight - div.clientHeight;
javascript:void(0);
preventDefault();
return false;
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: What you want your code to do, and what it does instead? There's no jumps when running the codepen (FF77).

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the issue with the following:

```
input {
  position:absolute;
  left: -100%;
  visibility: hidden;
  top: +20px;
}
```